# Decidable and recursively-axiomatizable theories

Tags: logic, incompleteness

A few questions:

1. If $T$ is a decidable and consistent theory, can there be any theory $T' \subset T$ that isn't decidable?
2. Is there a decidable theory which isn't complete?
3. How can I prove that any recursively-axiomatizable and complete in the number theory language $(+,*,S,0)$ is decidable?

Thanks.

Comment: I improved your formatting with the MathJax syntax that is available on this website. Have a good day!

Comment: For (2), there are many examples. Here is a boring one. Let $T$ be the theory over a language that has nothing but equality, and that says there are at most $2$ objects.

Answer (score 2):

$1.$  Let $T$ be the theory of algebraically closed fields of characteristic $0$. Then $T$ is decidable. Let $T'$ be the theory over the same language with all axioms removed. Or more interestingly let $T'$ be the theory of integral domains. Both of the $T'$ are undecidable: there is no algorithm that, on input any formula $\varphi$, will always halt, and report (correctly) whether or not $\varphi$ is a theorem of $T'$. The proof is by showing that within a suitable finite extension of $T'$, we can develop enough of arithmetic for the classical undecidability results to apply.

Or else let $T$ be the theory with a single binary relation symbol $R$, and axioms that say that $R$ is a dense order with no first or last element. This theory is decidable, but the theory of the single binary relation $R$ with no axioms is not decidable.

$2.$ Let $T$ be the theory over the language which has only the equality symbol, and that has axioms that say that there are at most two objects. Decidable (very), and incomplete.

$3.$ Here is an informal argument.   Given a sentence $\varphi$, start listing all formal proofs (of anything) systematically. If the theory is recursively axiomatized, there is an algorithm for generating all proofs.

For each proof, check whether one of $\varphi$ or $\lnot \varphi$ is at the end of the proof. If not, continue listing. By the assumed completeness of the theory, for any input $\varphi$ the algorithm will terminate.

Comment: Thanks! Regarding the third question, I wonder if there's a way of proving it using Godel's incompleteness theorem? Your argument is obviously valid, but is more of a Turing-machine proof than a mathematical one.

Comment: Well, it is the undecidability of weak versions of number theory. For the details, one has to prove that that there is a recursive predicate that says that $y$ is the number of a proof from the set of axioms coded by $w$. One goes through the details (and there are a lot of details!) when proving the undecidability of various versions of number theory, such as PA. The argument is fully "mathematical," we get a recursive description of the predicuate $P(x)$ that says that $x$ is the index of a theorem. For details, you can probably find information under $T$-predicate.